# Show which result was determinated by which combination of bindings in an ASK query

Tags: sparql

Is there a way to show which bindig of an `ASK` query was used for which result?

To clarify what I mean: For a `SELECT` query that's pretty easy:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {
 ?class_0 ?property_0 ?uri . 
 VALUES (?class_0) {(<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Angela_Merkel>) } 
 VALUES (?property_0) {(<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthPlace>) (<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate>) }
}
```

will give this:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                  class_0                   ║               property_0                ║                         uri                          ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ http://dbpedia.org/resource/Angela_Merkel  ║ http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthPlace  ║ http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hamburg                  ║
║ http://dbpedia.org/resource/Angela_Merkel  ║ http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthPlace  ║ http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barmbek-Nord             ║
║ http://dbpedia.org/resource/Angela_Merkel  ║ http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate   ║ 1954-07-17                                           ║
║ http://dbpedia.org/resource/Angela_Merkel  ║ http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate   ║ "1954-7-17"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date> ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

So I know exactly how the results were determinated:

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Angela_Merkel + http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthPlace -> http://dbpedia.org/resource/Hamburg, http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barmbek-Nord
```

Is there a way to get this information for the following query?

```
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> 
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
ASK WHERE { 
 ?class_0 a dbo:Sport . 
 VALUES (?class_0) {(dbr:Horse_racing) (dbr:Angela_Merkel)}
}
```

So I can see that

```
dbo:Sport + dbr:Horse_racing -> true
dbo:Sport + dbr:Angela_Merkel -> false
```

**Note:** I know it's possible to just split this query in two parts but I want to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Not with an ASK query - by the specs, this returns just a boolean value. But you could use a SELECT query and group by + count

Comment: Yeah, havn't thought about just using a SELECT but that would definitely do it. If you want you can post your comment as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPARQL `ASK` can only return a boolean value; thus, you can't use this query type.

This query might do what you want:

```sql
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> 
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
SELECT * WHERE { 
 VALUES (?class_0) {(dbr:Horse_racing) (dbr:Angela_Merkel)}
 BIND(xsd:boolean(exists{?class_0 a dbo:Sport}) as ?exists)
}
```